# Run PHP code after Jquery redirect prompt to another page

Tags: php, jquery, redirect, laravel

I am using Laravel as a PHP framework and I have Jquery set up so it prompts the user if they want to confirm redirecting away from the page or not.

The problem is that if the user confirms the redirect away from the page, I need to somehow perform some database operations to set various statues to closed on my tables.

How is this possible?

My Jquery code prompting the user

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});
```

Comment: I would have them always set as 'closed', unless a user completes an action. As in, rather than performing an action when a user leaves your site, I would focus on doing the equal opposite action if the user stays on your site.

Answer (score 0):

Just make an Ajax request to inform the server that the user will be redirectd.

```js
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e){
  if ( confirm("Are you sure you want to leave?") ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // make ajax request to inform the server
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: reqUrl,
       data: reqBody,
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(data, textStatus) {
          // handle things
       }
    });

    // Redirect.
    window.location.href = someURL;
  } 
});
```